# JDBC CONNECTION error in eclipse

Tags: jdbc

how to solve the following problem...

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200) at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)  at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307) at
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252) at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320) at
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169) at
com.myeclipseide.ws.FirstExample.main(FirstExample.java:20)
```

My JDBC driver file is `mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin`

My CLASSPATH variable is set to: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14`

My DB_URL is: `jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP`

My package is `com.myeclipseide.ws`
And I have pasted the class file of the class accessing jdbc driver in the path: `C:\Users\Mrinal\Workspaces\MyEclipse 10\restdemo\WebRoot\WEB-INF\lib....`
please help

Comment: I think eclipse is unable to find the JDBC driver file. 
Please double check the paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the problem is in your `forName` method argument. It should be

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Because

```
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169) at
```

This line from your Exception trace, says so!

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide more details.
I suppose, than the problem is in your class path because in exception text you have:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin
```

And there is definitely no such class with name mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin. The driver class name for mysql connector is *com.mysql.jdbc.Driver*.